# Need for country/region-state/city database

Tags: php, mysql, database, combobox, countries

I looked for the subject and found some questions in SO or other sites but I couldn't reach my goal.

I need a database with countries region-state and city database as in myip.ms but their price is very high for me I can't afford it.

I need the countries with country codes and regions to group them in select box. states with releated with them but states must have lat-lng şnfo to make me able to show my entries according to their states in google map. And the last one is the city as third select box.

If anybody can supply it for me I will be appraciated.

I realy tried to collect infos for this from varios sources but I stucked somewhere of the proccess.

Tkanks for your attention.

Comment: http://www.sqldumpster.com/databases/geographic/

Comment: http://www.openstreetmap.org/export ... and a lot more if you dig into the related pages/forums.

Comment: I am looking to Mark's link. I will inform you if I succeed. djot, I couln't export the data.

Comment: Mark I looked your link but it has price too. I need some free stuff since I am new in these things I am not sure i this works or not. And the that prices is a little high for my country and me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you plan on using IP addresses, you can use this API query to get location data from an IP address but don't expect 100% reliability

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.hostip.info/get_json.php?ip=".$IP_ADDRESS),true);
$country = $data['country_code'];
// I use this to ensure different strings don't get stored for null values
if($data['country_code'] == "XX" || $data['city'] == '(Unknown city)' || $data['city'] == '(Unknown city?)') {
    $city = "XX";
}
else {
    $city = $data['city'];
}
```

You get a JSON string returned with a few things that you can use, in my case I only stored the country code but if you need more specific data, chances are you'll have to pay for it or ask the user

Hope that helps mate

Edit: for future reference this is the answer to this problem:

> I've just found this one which has 6.6 million cities in the DB with country codes and should be mysql format [phpro.org/index.php?route=projects/geodb](http://phpro.org/index.php?route=projects/geodb)

Comment: I don't want to use any ip. Why every thing is releated with the ip. Yes it is useful when a user visit a page something related with the location of that ip can be shown to user. But I just want three dropdown boxes.

Comment: Oh sorry mate, I thought you wanted to query with a free service like myip.ms - if you just want to provide drop down menus then you may want to check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332685/is-there-a-centralized-list-of-country-names-that-can-be-used-for-web-drop-down

Comment: Dont't sorry everything adds informations to us ;). I looked it. Does it have only the countries. The problem is generllay with the states and cities :(.

Comment: Ah I respect that then :) right man I've done some looking and I believe that http://www.geonames.org/export/ is what you are looking for, you can search the dump but it isn't SQL format just tab separated data. I've also found http://www.geobytes.com/FreeServices.htm which has a GeoWorldMap download with the data you need

Comment: I already did what you say :D but I couldn't obtain proper database :/. I think I cal call myself as clumsy :D

Comment: To be honest the data there is a bit of a pain to work with, try this one maybe? http://www.maxmind.com/en/worldcities

Comment: Why ther is no such sql files that contains the table for those three :/

Comment: I've just found this one which has 6.6 million cities in the DB with country codes and should be mysql format http://phpro.org/index.php?route=projects/geodb - hope that one can solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
           <!-- ****************For State Loads Starts***************************-->
           $("#field6").change(function (e){
           var state = 
           {
           '0': ['Not Available'],
           'Z1':['Australian Capital Territory','New South Wales',
           'Northern Territory','Queensland','South Australia',
           'Tasmania','Victoria','Western Australia'],
           'IN':['Delhi','Maharashtra','TamilNadu','Karnataka','Haryana',
           'Uttar Pradesh','Andhra Pradesh','Jammu and Kashmir',
           'West Bengal','Gujarat','Madhya Pradesh','Kerala',
           'Punjab','Bihar','Rajasthan','Orissa','Assam','NA',
           'Himachal Pradesh','Chhattisgarh'],
           'MY':['Johor','Kedah','Kelantan','Kuala Lumpur','Labuan','Melaka',
           'Negeri Sembilan','Pahang','Penang','Perak','Perlis','Sabah',
           'Sarawak','Selangor','Terengganu'],
           'CN':['Beijing','Anhui','Chongqing','Fujian','Gansu','Guangdong',
           'Guangxi','Guizhou','Hainan','Hebei','Heilongjiang','Henan',
           'Hubei','Hunan','Jiangsu','Jiangxi','Jilin','Liaoning','Nei',
           'Mongol','Ningxia','Qinghai','Shaanxi','Shandong',
           'Shanghai','Shanxi','Sichuan','Tianjin',
           'Xinjiang','Xizang','(Tibet)','Yunnan','Zhejiang']
           }    
           var value = this.value;
           // Access the object like city['CT'] .. That gives the Array
           state[value] !== undefined ? state[value] : '0';                                 
           var stateOptions = state[value];         
           var $field8 = $('#field8'),
           $field9 = $('#field9');  
           $field8.html(''); // clear the existing options  
           $field9.html(''); // clear the existing options                
           $.each(stateOptions, function (i, o) {
           $('<option>' + o + '</option>').appendTo('#field8');
           });// ------------>each end tag          
           });//----------------->on-change end tag
           <!-- ****************For State Loads Ended***************************-->
           <!-- ****************For City Loads Starts***************************-->
           $("#field8").change(function (e){     
           var city = 
           {
           '0': ['Not Available'],
           'TamilNadu' : ['Coimbatore','Mettupalyam','Karur','Pollachi'],
           'Karnataka' : ['Bangalore','Mysore','Bellary','Mandya','Chikmagalur'
           ,'Chamarajanagar','Udupi','Chikkaballapura'],
           'Delhi'     : ['Faridabad','Panchkula','Sonipat','Hisar','Palwal','Thanesar']         
           }
           var value = this.value;
           city[value] !== undefined ? city[value] : '0';
           var cityOptions = city[value];
           var $field9 = $('#field9');              
           $field9.html(''); // clear the existing options 
           $.each(cityOptions, function (j, k) {
           $('<option>' + k + '</option>').appendTo('#field9');
           });// ------------>each end tag
           });//----------------->on-change end tag
           <!-- ****************For City Loads Ended***************************-->
           }); //-------------------->ready end tag
           </script>


           HTML Tag :

           <div id="formElement6" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <label for="Country" style="display: block; line-height: 150%; padding: 1px 0pt 3px; white-space: nowrap" >Country</label>
           <select id="field6" name="Country" style="width: 100%" >
           <option value="" selected="selected" >--Please Select--</option>
           <option value="YE" >Yemen</option>
           <option value="YT" >Mayotte</option>
           <option value="Z1" >Austria-SEAD</option>
           <option value="ZA" >South Africa</option>
           <option value="ZM" >Zambia</option>
           <option value="ZW" >Zimbabwe</option>
           <option value="ZY" >Taiwan(CO Only)</option>
           <option value="ZZ" >Others</option>
           <option value="AM" >Armenia</option>
           <option value="GB" >United Kingdom</option>
           <option value="SI" >Slovenia</option>
           <option value="LS" >Lesotho</option>
           <option value="MC" >Monaco</option>
           <option value="CU" >Cuba</option>
           <option value="SL" >Sierra Leone</option>
           <option value="FO" >Faroe Islands</option>
           <option value="GQ" >Equatorial Guin</option>
           <option value="IN" >India</option>
           <option value="KY" >Cayman Islands</option>
           <option value="ME" >Montenegro</option>
           <option value="MN" >Mongolia</option>
           <option value="AF" >Afghanistan</option>
           <option value="AZ" >Azerbaijan</option>
           <option value="BS" >Bahamas</option>
           <option value="CK" >Cook Islands</option>
           <option value="EC" >Ecuador</option>
           <option value="MY" >Malaysia</option>
           <option value="NZ" >New Zealand</option>
           <option value="QA" >Qatar</option>
           <option value="SJ" >Svalbard</option>
           <option value="IR" >Iran</option>
           <option value="KI" >Kiribati</option>
           <option value="LC" >St. Lucia</option>
           <option value="MD" >Moldova</option>
           <option value="BI" >Burundi</option>
           <option value="BW" >Botswana</option>
           <option value="CH" >Switzerland</option>
           <option value="CY" >Cyprus</option>
           <option value="PE" >Peru</option>
           <option value="PS" >Palestine</option>
           <option value="SA" >Saudi Arabia</option>
           <option value="SO" >Somalia</option>
           <option value="GY" >Guyana</option>
           <option value="KR" >South Korea</option>
           <option value="AO" >Angola</option>
           <option value="BZ" >Belize</option>
           <option value="MX" >Mexico</option>
           <option value="RU" >Russian Fed.</option>
           <option value="MR" >Mauretania</option>
           <option value="SH" >Saint Helena</option>
           <option value="FJ" >Fiji</option>
           <option value="FK" >Falkland Islnds</option>
           <option value="FM" >Micronesia</option>
           <option value="FR" >France</option>
           <option value="GA" >Gabon</option>
           <option value="GD" >Grenada</option>
           <option value="GE" >Georgia</option>
           <option value="GF" >French Guayana</option>
           <option value="GG" >GUERNSEY</option>
           <option value="GH" >Ghana</option>
           <option value="GI" >Gibraltar</option>
           <option value="GL" >Greenland</option>
           <option value="GM" >Gambia</option>
           <option value="GN" >Guinea</option>
           <option value="GP" >Guadeloupe</option>
           <option value="GR" >Greece</option>
           <option value="GS" >S. Sandwich Ins</option>
           <option value="GT" >Guatemala</option>
           <option value="GU" >Guam</option>
           <option value="GW" >Guinea-Bissau</option>
           <option value="HK" >Hong Kong</option>
           <option value="HM" >Heard/McDon.Isl</option>
           <option value="HN" >Honduras</option>
           <option value="HR" >Croatia</option>
           <option value="HT" >Haiti</option>
           <option value="HU" >Hungary</option>
           <option value="ID" >Indonesia</option>
           <option value="IE" >Ireland</option>
           <option value="IL" >Israel</option>
           <option value="IO" >Brit.Ind.Oc.Ter</option>
           <option value="IQ" >Iraq</option>
           <option value="IS" >Iceland</option>
           <option value="IT" >Italy</option>
           <option value="JE" >JERSEY</option>
           <option value="JM" >Jamaica</option>
           <option value="JO" >Jordan</option>
           <option value="JP" >Japan</option>
           <option value="KE" >Kenya</option>
           <option value="KG" >Kyrgyzstan</option>
           <option value="KH" >Cambodia</option>
           <option value="KM" >Comoros</option>
           <option value="KN" >St Kitts&amp;Nevis</option>
           <option value="KP" >North Korea</option>
           <option value="KW" >Kuwait</option>
           <option value="KZ" >Kazakhstan</option>
           <option value="LA" >Laos</option>
           <option value="LB" >Lebanon</option>
           <option value="LI" >Liechtenstein</option>
           <option value="LK" >Sri Lanka</option>
           <option value="LR" >Liberia</option>
           <option value="LT" >Lithuania</option>
           <option value="LU" >Luxembourg</option>
           <option value="LV" >Latvia</option>
           <option value="LY" >Libya</option>
           <option value="M4" >MIAMI</option>
           <option value="MA" >Morocco</option>
           <option value="MF" >SAINT MARTIN</option>
           <option value="MG" >Madagascar</option>
           <option value="MH" >Marshall Islnds</option>
           <option value="MK" >Macedonia</option>
           <option value="ML" >Mali</option>
           <option value="MM" >Myanmar</option>
           <option value="MO" >Macau</option>
           <option value="MP" >N.Mariana Islnd</option>
           <option value="MQ" >Martinique</option>
           <option value="MS" >Montserrat</option>
           <option value="MT" >Malta</option>
           <option value="AD" >Andorra</option>
           <option value="AE" >Utd.Arab Emir.</option>
           <option value="AG" >Antigua/Barbuda</option>
           <option value="AI" >Anguilla</option>
           <option value="AL" >Albania</option>
           <option value="AN" >Dutch Antilles</option>
           <option value="AQ" >Antarctica</option>
           <option value="AR" >Argentina</option>
           <option value="AS" >Samoa, America</option>
           <option value="AT" >Austria</option>
           <option value="AU" >Australia</option>
           <option value="AW" >Aruba</option>
           <option value="AX" >Åland</option>
           <option value="BA" >Bosnia-Herz.</option>
           <option value="BB" >Barbados</option>
           <option value="BD" >Bangladesh</option>
           <option value="BE" >Belgium</option>
           <option value="BF" >Burkina Faso</option>
           <option value="BG" >Bulgaria</option>
           <option value="BH" >Bahrain</option>
           <option value="BJ" >Benin</option>
           <option value="BL" >Blue</option>
           <option value="BM" >Bermuda</option>
           <option value="BN" >Brunei Daruss.</option>
           <option value="BO" >Bolivia</option>
           <option value="BR" >Brazil</option>
           <option value="BT" >Bhutan</option>
           <option value="BV" >Bouvet Islands</option>
           <option value="BY" >Belarus</option>
           <option value="C2" >Canary Island</option>
           <option value="C3" >CURACAO</option>
           <option value="CA" >Canada</option>
           <option value="CC" >Coconut Islands</option>
           <option value="CD" >Dem. Rep. Congo</option>
           <option value="CF" >CAR</option>
           <option value="CG" >Rep.of Congo</option>
           <option value="CI" >Cote d'Ivoire</option>
           <option value="CL" >Chile</option>
           <option value="CM" >Cameroon</option>
           <option value="CN" >China</option>
           <option value="CO" >Colombia</option>
           <option value="CR" >Costa Rica</option>
           <option value="CS" >Serbia/Monten.</option>
           <option value="CV" >Cape Verde</option>
           <option value="CX" >Christmas Islnd</option>
           <option value="CZ" >Czech Republic</option>
           <option value="DE" >Germany</option>
           <option value="DJ" >Djibouti</option>
           <option value="DK" >Denmark</option>
           <option value="DM" >Dominica</option>
           <option value="DO" >Dominican Rep.</option>
           <option value="DZ" >Algeria</option>
           <option value="EE" >Estonia</option>
           <option value="EG" >Egypt</option>
           <option value="EH" >West Sahara</option>
           <option value="ER" >Eritrea</option>
           <option value="ES" >Spain</option>
           <option value="ET" >Ethiopia</option>
           <option value="EU" >European Union</option>
           <option value="FI" >Finland</option>
           <option value="MU" >Mauritius</option>
           <option value="MV" >Maldives</option>
           <option value="MW" >Malawi</option>
           <option value="MZ" >Mozambique</option>
           <option value="NA" >Namibia</option>
           <option value="NC" >New Caledonia</option>
           <option value="NE" >Niger</option>
           <option value="NF" >Norfolk Islands</option>
           <option value="NG" >Nigeria</option>
           <option value="NI" >Nicaragua</option>
           <option value="NL" >Netherlands</option>
           <option value="NO" >Norway</option>
           <option value="NP" >Nepal</option>
           <option value="NR" >Nauru</option>
           <option value="NT" >NATO</option>
           <option value="NU" >Niue</option>
           <option value="OM" >Oman</option>
           <option value="OR" >Orange</option>
           <option value="PA" >Panama</option>
           <option value="PF" >Frenc.Polynesia</option>
           <option value="PG" >Pap. New Guinea</option>
           <option value="PH" >Philippines</option>
           <option value="PK" >Pakistan</option>
           <option value="PL" >Poland</option>
           <option value="PM" >St.Pier,Miquel.</option>
           <option value="PN" >Pitcairn Islnds</option>
           <option value="PR" >Puerto Rico</option>
           <option value="PT" >Portugal</option>
           <option value="PW" >Palau</option>
           <option value="PY" >Paraguay</option>
           <option value="RE" >Reunion</option>
           <option value="RO" >Romania</option>
           <option value="RS" >Serbia</option>
           <option value="RW" >Rwanda</option>
           <option value="S1" >SAIPAN</option>
           <option value="SB" >Solomon Islands</option>
           <option value="SC" >Seychelles</option>
           <option value="SD" >Sudan</option>
           <option value="SE" >Sweden</option>
           <option value="SG" >Singapore</option>
           <option value="SK" >Slovakia</option>
           <option value="SM" >San Marino</option>
           <option value="SN" >Senegal</option>
           <option value="SR" >Suriname</option>
           <option value="SS" >South Sudan</option>
           <option value="ST" >S.Tome,Principe</option>
           <option value="SV" >El Salvador</option>
           <option value="SY" >Syria</option>
           <option value="SZ" >Swaziland</option>
           <option value="T1" >TAHITI</option>
           <option value="TC" >Turksh Caicosin</option>
           <option value="TD" >Chad</option>
           <option value="TF" >French S.Territ</option>
           <option value="TG" >Togo</option>
           <option value="TH" >Thailand</option>
           <option value="TJ" >Tajikistan</option>
           <option value="TK" >Tokelau Islands</option>
           <option value="TL" >East Timor</option>
           <option value="TM" >Turkmenistan</option>
           <option value="TN" >Tunisia</option>
           <option value="TO" >Tonga</option>
           <option value="TP" >East Timor</option>
           <option value="TR" >Turkey</option>
           <option value="TT" >Trinidad,Tobago</option>
           <option value="TV" >Tuvalu</option>
           <option value="TW" >Taiwan</option>
           <option value="TZ" >Tanzania</option>
           <option value="UA" >Ukraine</option>
           <option value="UG" >Uganda</option>
           <option value="UM" >Minor Outl.Isl.</option>
           <option value="UN" >United Nations</option>
           <option value="US" >USA</option>
           <option value="UY" >Uruguay</option>
           <option value="UZ" >Uzbekistan</option>
           <option value="VA" >Vatican City</option>
           <option value="VC" >St. Vincent</option>
           <option value="VE" >Venezuela</option>
           <option value="VG" >Brit.Virgin Is.</option>
           <option value="VI" >Amer.Virgin Is.</option>
           <option value="VN" >Vietnam</option>
           <option value="VU" >Vanuatu</option>
           <option value="WF" >Wallis,Futuna</option>
           <option value="WS" >Samoa</option>
           <option value="XK" >Kosovo</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div id="formElement7" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <input id="field7" type="hidden" name="DataSource" value=""  />
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div id="formElement8" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <label for="state" style="display: block; line-height: 150%; padding: 1px 0pt 3px; white-space: nowrap" >State</label>
           <select id="field8" name="state" style="width: 100%" >
           <option value="First" >First</option>
           <option value="Second" >Second</option>
           <option value="Third" >Third</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
           <div id="formElement9" class="sc-view form-design-field sc-static-layout sc-regular-size" style="left: 0px; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; padding: 6px 5px 9px 9px" >
           <div class="field-wrapper" style="float: left; width: 100%; clear: both" >
           <div class="_100" style="float: left; width: 96%; margin-right: 2%; margin-left: 2%" >
           <p style="position: relative; margin: 0px; padding: 0px" >
           <label for="city" style="display: block; line-height: 150%; padding: 1px 0pt 3px; white-space: nowrap" >City</label>
           <select id="field9" name="city" style="width: 100%" >
           <option value="First" >First</option>
           <option value="Second" >Second</option>
           <option value="Third" >Third</option>
           </select>
           </p>
           </div>
           </div>
           </div>
```